# How to show dirty notification on tab header

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, mat-table

I have a page containing 3 tab-pages.
Each of this tabpages contains a list of items with CRUD possibilities.

I would like to show a dirty notification inside the tabheader, when a user has changed any of the items inside the tabcontent.

How can i do this?

My tabpages are created as followed:

```
          <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Specialisaties">
          <div class="tabContent">
            <dko-bo-onderneming-detail-specialisaties [ondernemingId]="onderneming.id"></dko-bo-onderneming-detail-specialisaties>
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Contactpersonen">
          <div class="tabContent">
            <dko-bo-onderneming-detail-contactpersonen [ondernemingId]="onderneming.id"></dko-bo-onderneming-detail-contactpersonen>
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Referenties">
          <div class="tabContent">
            <dko-bo-onderneming-detail-referenties [ondernemingId]="onderneming.id"></dko-bo-onderneming-detail-referenties>
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
```

For example, inside the dko-bo-onderneming-detail-referenties i monitor when the data changes:

```
addReferentie = function (referentiePersoon: ReferentiePersoon) {
    ...
    this.isDirtyReferentiePersonen = true;
};
deleteReferentie = function(referentiePersoon: ReferentiePersoon) {
    ...
    this.isDirtyReferentiePersonen = true;
};
```

So when i change the isDirtyReferentiePersonen property, i would like to update the tab-header 'Referenties' to show an * when i set the property to true

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. In your child components, add an output event

`@Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();`

2. Emit the event when a change is detected from the child

`valueChanged() { this.valueChange.emit(true); }`

3. Use the event in the parent component to change the mat tab label

`updateTabLabel` can then modify the tab label using data binding.

```
updateTabLabel($event){
  if($event)
  {
     this.ondernemingLabel = 'Referenties *';
  }else{
     this.ondernemingLabel = 'Referenties';
  }

}
```

So `<mat-tab label="Referenties">` becomes `<mat-tab [label]="ondernemingLabel">`

[More info on component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect

Comment: Fantastic! Please mark it as answer so that others can benefit.